# wordpress contact form 7 datepicker disable

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, contact-form-7

I am new in Wordpress and I don't know how to disable datepicker. I just want to fill the date field manually without any UI. Where I can disable it?

Comment: You could just edit your form (Dashboard > Contact Form 7) and change the field type from date to text. See here for more: [Contact Form 7 - Text fields](https://contactform7.com/text-fields/).

Comment: That’s a great idea

Answer (score 1):

In contact form 7 plugin, when create / edit a form, you can use textbox instead of date field. Example:

```
<label> Your date:
    [text text-480]
</label>
```